# DNS on Window Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Hello everyone in Server Fault, I am a big geek. I have an IBM x306 server at home, and i bought window server 2008 text book and lab book. I am hoping I am asking this question correctly if not I am sorry. I don't want to pay for a DNS, is there any free webstes out there? Thank you!

Edit/clarification:

*I am setting up Active Directory in four sections in Window Server 2008 bible lab book chapter 7, section 7-8. I am not looking to host my own DNS. It just told me to go into "Add Roles" and install DNS and when I set my static IP up, I can't connect to the internet. So I went on a fourm and they said, I need to pay for a DNS.*

Comment: If you don't need the names to be usable on the Internet, then you can use anything you want and you don't have to pay anyone.

Comment: What did we just learn you about cross-posting? (http://superuser.com/questions/125423/dns-on-window-server-2008)

Comment: did you setup dns forwarding?

Comment: @fretje: actually to be fair, somebody over there told SysPrep2010 to post the question here. So, I won't close the question.

Comment: @splattne: Fair enough. I was just alluding on http://serverfault.com/questions/127354/hotmail-account-closed in which somebody told him to *not* re-post on SU it as it would get migrated there.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking to use DNS for?

1. Are you setting up Active Directory? If so, local DNS is mandatory, but free as it is part of the Directory setup.
2. Are you looking to host your own DNS for a website?

Comment: I am setting up active directory in four sections in window server 2008 bible lab book chapter 7, section 7-8. I am not looking to host my own dns. It just told me to go into add roles and install dns and when I set my static ip up, I can't connect to the internet. So I went on a fourm and they said, i need to pay for a dns. So I am here.

Comment: Once you get local DNS setup properly, you will be able to connect to the internet, something in your config is missing.

Answer (score 1):

So to set up AD you need to host your own private DNS server.  Adding the DNS role and creating a zone like lab.internal or lab.test will allow you to create an AD and if you want to use that DNS server to resolve outside addresses you also need to set up DNS forwarding.

You do not need to pay for this, you would also only need to pay for it if you wanted to set up and external facing DNS server - and then you would need to own the domain.  Normally I would post steps to perform the actions required but since this is a learning exercise I don't want to spoil the fun. Post additional specific questions if you get stuck along the way.